# Functional approach to file parsing in Python

Tags: python, functional-programming

I have a text file describing an electronic circuit and a few other things done with it. I've built a simple Python code that splits the file into different units which can then be further analyzed if needed.
The syntax of the simulation language defines these units as contained within the following lines:

```
subckt xxx .....
...
...
ends xxx ...
```

There is a few of these 'text blocks' and other stuff I'm parsing or leaving out - like comment lines.

To accomplish this, I use the following core:

```
with open('input') as f:
    for l in iter(f):
        if 'subckt' not in l:
             pass
        else:
            with open('output') as o:
                 o.write(l)
                 for l in iter(f):
                     if 'ends' in l:
                         o.write(l)
                         break
                     else:
                         o.write(l)
```

(can't easily paste the real code, there might be oversights)

The nice thing about it is the fact that `iter(f)` keeps scanning the file so when I break out of the inner loop as I reached the `ends` line of a `subckt`, the outer loop keeps going from that point onward, searching for new occurrences of the token `subckt` in subsequent lines.

I am looking for suggestions and/or guidance on how to transform the forest of `if/then` clauses into something more functional, i.e. based on 'pure' functions which just yield values (the file rows or lines) and are then composed as to bring to the final result.

Specifically, I am not sure how to approach the fact that the `generator\map\filter` should actually yield a different row based on the fact that it has found the `subckt` token or not.
I can think of a `filter` of the form:

```
line = filter(lambda x: 'subckt' in x, iter(f))
```

but this of course only gives me the lines where  that string is present, whereas I would like - from that moment on - `yield` *all* lines, until the `ends` token is found.
Is this something I'd have to handle with recursion? Or maybe `itertools.tee`?

Seems to me that what I want is to have some form of state, i.e. "you have reached a subckt", but without resorting to a true state variable, which would be against the functional paradigm.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for. `blocks(f)` is a generator producing the blocks in your file `f`. Each block is an iterator over the lines between 'subckt' and 'ends'. If you want to include those two lines in the block, you'd have to do some more work in `_blocks`. But I hope this gives you an idea:

```
def __block(f):
    while 'subckt' not in next(f): pass  # raises StopIteration at EOF
    return iter(next(iter([])) if 'ends' in l else l.strip() for l in f)

def blocks(f):
    while 1: yield __block(f)  # StopIteration from __block will stop the generator

f = open('data.txt')
for block in blocks(f):
    # process block
    for line in block:
        # process line
```

`next(iter([])) if` is a little hack to terminate a comprehension/generator.

Comment: Thanks @schwobaseggl, this certainly does what I was asking.
I have come with a slightly different solution which I will post as an aswer: I would be grateful if you commented on that.

Answer (score 0):

This answer also works, still very keen on hearing comments:

```
from itertools import takewhile, dropwhile

def start(l): return 'subckt' not in l
def stop(l): return 'ends' not in l

def sub(iter):    
    while True:    
        a =   list(dropwhile(start,takewhile(stop,iter)))      
        if len(a):
            yield a
        else:
            return
f = open('file.txt')
for b in sub(f):
    #process b
f.close()
```

Something I couldn't work out yet: enclose the last line (containing `ends` keyword) in the output.